# Is it ok to limit writes on SSD/EXT4 by setting commit parameter in fstab?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, ext4

I have installed an SSD on my */* (`Linux scv 3.8.0-34-generic #49~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 13 18:05:00 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`).

If I leave the default settings in */etc/fstab* I can see disk activity (`sudo iotop --only -d 3`) every 5 seconds on */dev/sdd1* (where */* is mounted) by process `jbd2/sdd1-8`. If I'm not mistaken this is due to the *commit* settings for this partition.

In order to avoid this, I've set the following options in */etc/fstab*:

```
# / was on /dev/sdd1 during installation
UUID=70ec8672-295c-45e3-807c-905c90b00fb3 /               ext4    noatime,discard,commit=30,errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

As you can see I've left *commit=30* to ensure writes happen only every 30 seconds.

Have I understood the issue correctly?
Is my solution to these continuous writes ok?

Thanks,
Ema

Comment: Why do you need a solution? Are these writes causing you some kind of problem?

Comment: I was reading around a lot of unnecessary writes on SSD are just impacting on the H/W, reducing its lifespan.

Comment: I believe just about every SSD available these days is created to be functional for many more writes than the drive will ever see. Any decent drive should be good for many [hundreds of terabytes of writes](http://techreport.com/review/25681/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-testing-data-retention-at-300tb). Anyways, changing the commit changes how often it's written, shouldn't matter that much except to encourage filesystem corruption.

Comment: So changing from default 5 seconds to 30 seconds should increase corruption? You mean only in the case of a power outage, right? Btw I've got a UPS so this should be a quite rare event..